# Сопоставление данных из списков XML

Tags: xml, xsd

Всем доброго времени суток. Можно ли как-нибудь в xml использовать сопоставленные значения из справочника, если выбранные значения несопоставимы то валидация относительно схемы должна выдавать ошибку. К примеру вывод сложного типа

```
<complexType name="address">
 <element name="street" type="street"/>
 <element name="house" type="house"/>
</complexType>
```

Можно сделать простые типы с названиями улиц и номерами домов, которые могут быть доступны в элементах. Но как сделать сопоставление, к примеру на улице "А" нет дома "10" и при таком совпадении значений будет ошибка валидации. Или даже невозможно будет выбрать такое сочетание. Возможно есть другие способы построения таких элементов. Подскажите пожалуйста, заранее спасибо.

Comment: Справочники будут лежать в этом же XML? Приведите их формат. Или вы хотите задать справочники в схеме?

Comment: отдельные xsd файлы в которых находятся `simpleType`. Но это только предположение, как при такой конструкции сопоставлять значения(и можно ли так делать) я не знаю

Comment: Нет. Так работать не будет. Элемент с конкретным именем должен иметь строго определенный тип. А вот если справочники поместить в сам XML (или указать ссылку на него через `xi:include`, при условии, что ваш парсер поддерживает xi:include), то можно реализовать проверку ссылочной целостности

Comment: XSD какой версии можете использовать? В XSD 1.1 появились assertions. С помощью них, возможно, это получится сделать.

Comment: @AntonShchyrov можно немного разжевать пожалуйста) Если делать отдельными файлами справочниками, то да надо использовать `import` или `include`. Про проверку ссылочной целостности можно подробнее, не пойму как оно поможет сопоставить значения